# Segfault sharing array between assembly and C++

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I am writing a program that has a shared state between assembly and C++. I declared a global array in the assembly file and accessed that array in a function within C++. When I call that function from within C++, there are no issues, but then I call that same function from within assembly and I get a segmentation fault. I believe I preserved the right registers across function calls.

Strangely, when I change the type of the pointer within C++ to a uint64_t pointer, it correctly outputs the values but then segmentation faults again after casting it to a uint64_t.

In the following code, the array which keeps giving me errors is currentCPUState.

```
//CPU.cpp
extern uint64_t currentCPUState[6];

extern "C" {
    void initInternalState(void* instructions, int indexSize);
    void printCPUState();
}

void printCPUState() {
    uint64_t b = currentCPUState[0];
    printf("%d\n", b);        //this line DOESNT crash ???
    std::cout << b << "\n"; //this line crashes

    //omitted some code for the sake of brevity

    std::cout << "\n";
}

CPU::CPU() {
    //set initial cpu state
    currentCPUState[AF] = 0;
    currentCPUState[BC] = 0;
    currentCPUState[DE] = 0;
    currentCPUState[HL] = 0;
    currentCPUState[SP] = 0;
    currentCPUState[PC] = 0;
    
    printCPUState(); //this has no issues

    initInternalState(instructions, sizeof(void*));
}
```

```
//cpu.s
.section .data
    .balign 8

    instructionArr:
        .space 8 * 1024, 0

    //stores values of registers
    //used for transitioning between C and ASM
    //uint64_t currentCPUState[6]
    .global currentCPUState
    currentCPUState:
        .quad 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

.section .text
    .global initInternalState
    initInternalState:
        push %rdi
        push %rsi
        mov %rcx, %rdi
        mov %rdx, %rsi

        push %R12
        push %R13
        push %R14
        push %R15

        call initGBCpu

        pop %R15
        pop %R14
        pop %R13
        pop %R12

        pop %rsi
        pop %rdi
        ret

    //omitted unimportant code
    //initGBCpu(rdi: void* instructions, rsi:int size)
    //function initializes the array of opcodes
    initGBCpu:
        pushq %rdx
        //move each instruction into the array in proper order
        //also fill the instructionArr
        leaq instructionArr(%rip), %rdx

        addop inst0x00
        addop inst0x01
        addop inst0x02
        addop inst0x03
        addop inst0x04

        call loadCPUState
        call inst0x04   //inc BC
        call saveCPUState
        call printCPUState    //CRASHES HERE
        popq %rdx
        ret
```

Additional details:
OS: Windows 64 bit
Compiler (MinGW64-w)
Architecture: x64

Any insight would be much appreciated

Edit:
addop is a macro:

```
//adds an opcode to the array of functions
.macro addop lbl
    leaq \lbl (%rip), %rcx
    mov %rcx, 0(%rdi)
    mov %rcx, 0(%rdx)
    add %rsi, %rdi
    add %rsi, %rdx
.endm
```

Comment: What is `addop`?

Comment: addop is just a macro that adds elements to the function pointer array. It only changes RDI and RDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of [x86-64 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) require that the stack have to be alligned to 16-byte boundary before calling functions.

After functions are called, a 8-byte return address is pushed on the stack, so another 8-byte data have to be added to the stack to satisfy this allignment requirement. Otherwise, some instruction with allignment requirement (like some of the SSE instructions) may crash.

Assumign that such calling conventions are applied, the `initGBCpu` function looks OK, but the `initInternalState` function have to add one more 8-byte thing to the stack before calling the `initInternalState` function.

For example:

```
    initInternalState:
        push %rdi
        push %rsi
        mov %rcx, %rdi
        mov %rdx, %rsi

        push %R12
        push %R13
        push %R14
        push %R15

        sub $8, %rsp // adjust stack allignment
        call initGBCpu
        add $8, %rsp // undo the stack pointer movement

        pop %R15
        pop %R14
        pop %R13
        pop %R12

        pop %rsi
        pop %rdi
        ret
```